# sorting an array of object with respect to the float value

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

im working with a project , where i receive an array of object, each object has a description of type string, and a value of type CGfloat.
i need to sort them by value increasingly, and store them in a dicitonary.
i tried this solution, but it didn't work.
[How do I sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-do-i-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)
any idea how to do it?

```
for (PNPieChartDataItem *item in items) {// didnt work
NSArray *sortedArray;
        sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            CGFloat first = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)a value];
            CGFloat second = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)b value];
            return [first compare:second];
        }];


        }
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: answer updated, check please

Comment: Should it be `CGfloat *first` or `CGfloat first` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop, `sortedArrayUsingComparator` iterates on values to compare:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
            CGFloat first = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)a value];
            CGFloat second = [(PNPieChartDataItem*)b value];
            return [first compare:second];
        }];
}
```

Use `sortedArray`.

Comment: `CGFloat` is not an object, so one wouldn't call methods on it.

Comment: im getting an error bar receiver type 'cgfloat' (aka 'double') at the return line

Comment: what is the type of `value` ? Try changing `CGFloat` to `double`.